# pptpd ubuntu работает ровно минуту и затыкается

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

Добрый день. На инстансе амазон AWS стоит ubuntu. Поднят pptpd. Работал вроде нормально. Цеплялся из под винды и мака. Но на прошлой недели обновил  мак до Sierra. Там удалили возможность использовать  PPTP vpn. Теперь приходиться сторонние программы типа Shimo или VPN Tracker. А с ними интересная беда. Соединение живет ровно минут и затыкается. Причем соединение не падает а просто затыкается пакеты с клиента улетают а в ответ не прилетает ничего.
Вот лог:

```
eb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pptpd[10131]: CTRL: Sending ECHO REQ id 1

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pptpd[10131]: CTRL: Made a ECHO REQ packet

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pptpd[10131]: CTRL: I wrote 16 bytes to the client.

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pptpd[10131]: CTRL: Sent packet to client

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pptpd[10131]: CTRL: EOF or bad error reading ctrl packet length.

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pptpd[10131]: CTRL: couldn't read packet header (exit)

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pptpd[10131]: CTRL: CTRL read failed

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pptpd[10131]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[10132]

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: Hangup (SIGHUP)

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: Modem hangup

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: pptpd-logwtmp.so ip-down ppp0

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: Connect time 1.0 minutes.

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: Sent 136764 bytes, received 67167 bytes.

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-down started (pid 10221)

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: MPPE disabled

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "MPPE disabled"]

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: Connection terminated.

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: Waiting for 1 child processes...

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]:   script /etc/ppp/ip-down, pid 10221

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: Script /etc/ppp/ip-down finished (pid 10221), status = 0x0

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pppd[10132]: Exit.

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pptpd[10131]: CTRL: Client 91.201.110.166 control connection finished

Feb 17 15:22:10 ip-172-31-52-255 pptpd[10131]: CTRL: Exiting now
```

В начале грешил что эти клиенты криво написаны, но они прекрасно цепляются за другой сервер под FreBsd там поднят mpd5. Начал грешить на криво настроенный сервер. Но на него прекрасно цепляется клиент из под винды и не падает.
Вобщем кто что может, подскажите господа.

Comment: вероятно, клиенту надо как-то объяснить, что *"MPPE disabled"*, и не надо пытаться его использовать.

Comment: MPPE  на самом деле не disabled, но я пробовал и без шифрации то же самое. канал живет одну минуту.... Какая то мистика, виндовский клиент прекасно работает. И этот клиент из мака тоже работает на на других серверах.